# Spring boot serve static content: addResourceLocations vs static-locations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a standard Spring Boot app and try to serve some static content. I want to change the location to a specific folder on the filesystem. These seem to be the most common approaches:

Set the path in application.yaml

```
spring:
  resources:
    static-locations: "file:/here/some/path"
```

Use `WebMvcConfigurer`

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:/here/some/path");
    }
}
```

Here is my problem: the first approach works, the second does not and I can not figure out why. Any hints?

Is there a difference between setting "static-locations" and "addResourceLocations"? What would be a starting point to debug?

I would like to use the second one because I want to set the path depending on a specific condition.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed it was actually working with

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:/here/some/path");
    }
}
```

**BUT** for some reason redirecting to index.html got disabled (which is quite some unexpected behaviour). So I needed to add it manually.

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:/here/some/path");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that, in most regular apps, one would not use `file:...` but `classpath:/here/some/path/`. This is because all resources are zipped in a .jar (or .war) and files are not on the filesystem in the deployed environment, and the `file:...` reference won't work anymore, unless specific circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add trailing slash to "file:/here/some/path"

When you use "spring.resources.static-locations" it's automagically done for you at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ResourceProperties#appendSlashIfNecessary

Answer (score 0):

Append this annotation

> @EnableWebMvc

in your  **MvcConfig** class.Just try it will solve your problem.

Comment: [If you want to keep Spring Boot MVC features and you want to add additional MVC configuration (interceptors, formatters, view controllers, and other features), you can add your own @Configuration class of type WebMvcConfigurer but without @EnableWebMvc.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration)